# Laravel queued jobs processed immediately even with a delay

Tags: php, laravel-5, jobs

I'm currently developing my personal application that is about private servers (for example, [Minecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minecraft) servers) and since querying the server takes some time, I decided to implement queued jobs. However, they are not working properly, and they run immediately when called even though they are delayed, causing a massive latency in a page request.

Here's my HomeController's index() which calls the job to update every server with a 30 seconds delay:

```
public function index()
{
    $servers = Server::all();

    foreach($servers as $server)
    {
        // Job Dispatch
        $job = (new UpdateServer($server->id))->delay(30);
        $this->dispatch($job);
    }
    return view('serverlist.index', compact('servers'));
}
```

The job class that updates the servers is the following:

```
class UpdateServer extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;
    protected $id;

    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function handle(){
        $server = Server::findOrFail($this->id);

        // Preparing the packet
        $test = new RAGBuffer();
        $test->addChar('255');
        $test->addChar('1');
        $test->addShort(1 | 8);

        // Finding the server
        $serverGame = new RAGServer($server->server_ip);

        // Get server information
        $status = $serverGame->sendPacket($test);

        $server->onlinePlayers = $status->getOnline();
        $server->peakPlayers = $status->getPeak();
        $server->maxPlayers = $status->getMax();

        if (!$server->save()) {
            // Error occurred
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever the HomeController's index() is run, there's a massive delay in the page request. I followed the tutorial at Laravel's Official Webpage, and I tried to find answers, but I didn't find anything.

So, what am I doing wrong? Why isn't the job getting delayed 30 seconds and then doing this in background in my server?

Also: The handle() is doing what it is supposed to. It queries the server, sends packets, and updates my database with the correct information.

Comment: I had issues using `dispatch()`. When I switched to `\Queue::later(delay,job)` things started working.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You have to set up the queue driver you want to use in your project's root dir's `.env` file.

By default, the queue driver is `sync` which does exactly what you are describing, executing queues immediately.

You can choose of some different queue drivers, such as beanstalked or redis (which would be my choice). There's an [**excellent freebie**](https://laracasts.com/lessons/beanstalkd-queues-with-laravel) on laracasts.com about setting up a beanstalked queue.

To view all available queue driver options in Laravel, have a look [**here**](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues).

Here's a .env example

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=SomeRandomString

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync      // <-- Put the desired driver here

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I guess I'll try beanstalked queue then, so, from what I understand it works like a background process right? It won't influence the load time of a page or anything?

Comment: Should not have any influence (apart from the bandwidth if you are down- or uploading something with your script, but that shouldn't be a problem). Beanstalked is a good choice, if you follow the video it is setup within a few minutes.

Comment: Too bad I do not have an account in laracasts since it's needed, will try to follow other tutorial, will mark your question as accepted as soon as I get this to work, thank you for your time!

Comment: This is another great post that helped me get setup. It gives a step-by-step to getting configured. https://scotch.io/tutorials/why-laravel-queues-are-awesome

Answer (score 29):

This was driving me crazy for ages before I realised that Laravel 5.7 renamed QUEUE_DRIVER to QUEUE_CONNECTION in the .env files

Comment: Oh my gosh. Thank you. Just happened to me too.

Answer (score 10):

For someone who has made the changes from previous answers and still didn't work, check the default value of the queue file like this: `dd(Config::get('queue.default'))`

For me it didn't change until flushing the config cache:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: For local development restarting the artisan server should do the trick (I often forget about that)

Answer (score 7):

To test locally you could set the driver to

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

And run **php artisan queue:table**.

And then **php artisan migrate**, so you would get your queue saved into the database, so you visually could see what`s going on.

And to run your queues, simply run **php artisan queue:listen** ... and leave it running as you do with `artisan serve`.

Comment: It is necessary to run the `queue:listen` command for the queue to work! thank you

Answer (score 6):

If you are running on `php artisan serve`, restart this and run `php artisan serve` again. This worked for me after hours trying to wonder what it was.
:)

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'database'),
```

in file *config/queue.php*

And

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

in the .env file to ensure the database driver is used.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running tests against the queue service through phpunit, make sure that

```
<env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="X"/>
```

in phpunit.xml doesn't override your desired queue driver.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the delay function takes an absolute date in the future

```
UpdateServer::dispatch($server->id)->delay(now()->addSeconds(30))
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to implement `ShouldQueue` and use the `Queueable` trait:

```
class CustomNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue{
    use Queueable;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have configured everything properly this can still happen. We had this problem with Laravel 5.4 where we created a lot of jobs, some delayed, and added them to the queue via `Queue:bulk($jobs)`. This call and also `Queue::push($job)` completely ignore the `delay` and cause the job to be processed immediately.

If you want your job to be put on the queue as you configured it you must call `dispatch($job)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete steps to create user API and store its history in jobs table.
In Jobs class:

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\Repositories\Eloquent\ApiRepo as ApiRepo;
use Log;
use App\Models\User;

class UserProcess implements ShouldQueue
{
     use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

     /**
     * The number of times the job may be attempted and override the queue tries.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $tries = 3;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user; 
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {       
        try {
            // make api call
           Log::info("inside handle".$this->user->id);
            $apiRepo = new ApiRepo;
            $response = $apiRepo->getUserDetails($this->user->id);
            Log::info("Response".$response);
        } catch (\Throwable $exception) {
            if ($this->attempts() > 3) {
                // hard fail after 3 attempts
                throw $exception;
            }
            // requeue this job to be executes
            // in 3 minutes (180 seconds) from now
            $this->release(180);
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

In Controller Class:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Jobs\UserProcess;
use App\Models\UserHistory;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $rules = [
            'first_name' => 'required|string|max:100',
            'last_name' => 'required|string|max:100',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users,email',
            'phone_number' => 'required|string|max:10',
            'address' => 'string',
            'date_of_birth' => 'string|date_format:Y-m-d|before:today',
            'is_vaccinated' => 'string|in:YES,NO',
            'vaccine_name' => 'string|required_if:is_vaccinated,==,YES|in:COVAXIN,COVISHIELD'
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make(array_map('trim', ($request->all())),$rules);

        if($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json($validator->errors());       
        }else{
            $user = new User;
            $user->first_name = $request->first_name;
            $user->last_name = $request->last_name;
            $user->email = $request->email;
            $user->phone_number = $request->phone_number;
            $user->address = $request->address;
            $user->date_of_birth = $request->date_of_birth;
            $user->is_vaccinated = $request->is_vaccinated;
            $user->vaccine_name = $request->vaccine_name;
            $user->save();

            $token = $user->createToken('auth_token')->plainTextToken;
            if($user->save()){
                $job = (new UserProcess($user))->delay(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(1));
                $this->dispatch($job);
            
                return response()
                ->json(['data' => $user,'status' => '200','message' => 'User Added Successfully','access_token' => $token, 'token_type' => 'Bearer']);
            }else{
                return response()
                ->json(['data' => $user,'status' => '409','message' => 'Something went wrong!']);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

In ApiRepo Class:

```
namespace App\Repositories\Eloquent;

use App\Repositories\ApiInterface;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\UserHistory;
use Log;

class ApiRepo implements ApiInterface {

     public function getUserDetails($userid) {
        Log::info('User ID - '.@$userid);
        $user_history = new UserHistory();
        $save_user = User::find($userid);
        Log::info('User Json Data - '.@$save_user);
        $user_history->user_id = $userid;
        $user_history->first_name = $save_user->first_name;
        $user_history->last_name = $save_user->last_name;
        $user_history->email = $save_user->email ;
        $user_history->phone_number = $save_user->phone_number;
        $user_history->address = $save_user->address;
        $user_history->date_of_birth = $save_user->date_of_birth;
        $user_history->is_vaccinated = $save_user->is_vaccinated;
        $user_history->vaccine_name = $save_user->vaccine_name;
        $user_history->save();
        if($user_history->save()){
            Log::info('User history Saved!');
        }
     }
}
```