# Queues are executed instantly without delay

Tags: laravel

i am using postgresql as db, in .env i have set QUEUE_CONNECTION = database

I download from url, for example, a picture and transfer it to the queue for uploading in storage laravel

In web.php, I registered a route to the queue

```
Route::get('/job', function () {
    App\Jobs\FileAdd::dispatch("https://www.example.com/example.jpg")->delay(now()->addMinute(25));
});
```

In job, I wrote the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;


class FileAdd implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    protected $File;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($File)
    {
        $this->File = $File;


    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {

        info($data = $this->File);

        $pos = strripos($data, '/');

        $link = substr($data, 0 , $pos+1);
        $filename = substr($data, $pos+1);
        $expansion = substr($filename, -4);
        $tempImageTwink = tempnam('..\storage\app\public', $filename);
        $tempImage = substr($tempImageTwink, 0, -4) . $expansion;
        copy($link . '/' . $filename, $tempImage);
        Storage::delete('exa3BBD.tmp');
        response()->download($tempImage, $filename);
        unlink(($tempImageTwink ));
    }
}
```

in the database I have two tables jobs, failed_jobs, for writing queues, but they are executed immediately without delay, what could be the problem?

Comment: Try this in delay method as `delay(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(25))`

Comment: He is already doing so, `now()` is an alias for `Carbon::now()`, you also have `today()` as `Carbon::today()`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel queued jobs processed immediately even with a delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31091535/laravel-queued-jobs-processed-immediately-even-with-a-delay)

Answer (score -2):

Might be problem with cache if you just change it in .env file. Laravel cache your .env file and look at the cache if it is available not the .env file itself. So changes is not active, unless you will clear you cache or create new one. Try clear your cache with:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

or

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

so new data from .env file can be loaded.